# Moving at least two words to the next line in paragraph

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, paragraph-styles, formatting

I hate it when the paragraph ends with one word on the the last line. It's just not right for it to hang there by itself like that. Is there a way to force the last line to have at least 2 words?

Comment: In my experience one generally has to "massage" the text, inserting a soft-return somewhere in the paragraph causing the text to warp just slightly different. Maybe there's an automated method (other than adjusting the document hyphenation) I'm clueless about.

Comment: I agree with Scott. This seems like something that has to manually be changed. When I design something, I have a general idea of how large text is going to be. I make small adjustments to the text to align the text to how I see best fit. Small changes can be made by increasing.decreasing fractions of a font pt, use tracking or soft return.

Answer (score 1):

I believe single words on the last line of a paragraph are called [*orphans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans), and there's no specific setting to avoid these. You have 2 options:

1. manually adjust where each line ends, so you can control where the last line ends
2. turn on the *Balance Ragged Lines* feature via the *Paragraph* panel flyout menu, which will optically adjust the entire paragraph, so that all the lines become more ... well, *balanced* in length, and this in most cases results in *orphans* getting resolved

[image]

[image]

Comment: ah, this solution seems reasonable.